# Play Framework 2.2.6. Can not add JsMessages

Tags: java, playframework

I am new at java play framework. I am trying to use JsMessages in this link 
https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages
I add this line to build.sbt

> libraryDependencies += "org.julienrf" %% "play-jsmessages" % "1.6.1"

When i use "play run", my project download some jar file, i thought that okay but i cant use JsMessage class, i check referenced libraries and no new jar file has been add. 
Wonder what am i doing wrong. 
Thank you guys

Comment: Referenced libraries in your IDE? Did you try to reload the project? Does your project compile if you import a class from that library?

Comment: I try to reload my project, use play - clean - complie again.
I cant complie my project when i import JsMessage, my quick tip does not show up any class to it.
I think my project just download jar file but its not add it to use

Comment: Can you please add the compile exception?

Comment: Its tell me not recognize symbol JsMessages. I add play-jsmessages_2.10-1.6.1.jar by class path then it work but my co-work must add them too. I want to write it in buid.sbt like recommend in github to auto use this jar

Comment: Oh yeah, i know why. I must eclipse my project before to recognize that class. Thank you, Roman

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You should answer your own question now with your findings. Others will be thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

for me i ran command "activator eclipse" ,then f5 it will reload the libraries in eclipse for example, make it the same for intelliji or other editor...

and then i can use import.

Sometime run "activator compile" or "activator clean" and then activator compile"

or play instead activator in older version.

It worked for me !